# During background method execution Firefox doesn't allow to navigate elsewhere

Tags: firefox, jsf-2, browser, oracle-adf, webcenter

Here is the scenario:
My application has a home page which contains different regions. The page loads all the regions instead of one which is running with separate thread and taking long time. Now during the execution of long running task, if user wants to navigate to another page by clicking on a command link or goLink then it works on google chrome and IE but doesn't work with Firefox. In case of firefox once it seems to redirecting to desired url for a while but then it redirects back to same page. Surprisingly, It works perfectly once the execution of long running task is finished. So it seems problem with firefox's handling of asynchronous requests. I tried FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(url) and setting the URL as destination for goLink to navigate. 
Below is the code for goLink and commandLink:

af:goLink id="pt_g22" text="#{node.title}"                                      destination="#{contextroot}/faces/test.jsp"
styleClass="#{node.selected ? 'ln_active' : ''}"/>

af:commandLink id="pt_c21" text="#{node.title}" action="pprnav"
clientComponent="#{node.attributes['Target'] == '_popup' ? true : false}" 
styleClass="#{node.selected ? 'ln_active' : ''}" actionListener="#{MyBean.navigateToHere}"                                              partialSubmit="true">

in commandLink's actionListener method i am just having : FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(url)

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Why using redirect urls while you can use goLinks and goButton and enter the url destination instead!

Comment: If you have active request from your application to the server with reply pending, all other action shouldn't work properly or work at all. You can still use direct link to navigate away though. May be you should deal with the long running task instead? Send it to background for example?

Comment: @AmrGawish Thanks for your suggestion but even using goLinks doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Nagh Can you please elaborate direct link with example? Actually the navigation works perfectly in IE and Chrome even if any reply is pending from server(task in separate thread). The issue is only with Firefox.

Comment: @JitenderKaswan There are quite a lot of variations. Can you provide your code for navigation instead, so we can think in your terms of code and situation?

Comment: @Nagh I've edited my question please have a look.

Comment: @JitenderKaswan well, goLink should work for sure in any situation. Since it rendered to <a href=""> tag. May be your browser are too busy with handling javascript or something to react? Check with firebug code for goLink. Only way to prevent it - do some handling with javascript and explictly cancelling event. BTW what version of webcenter you are using?

Comment: @JitenderKaswan I've did a quick dirty test. And confirming suggested behavior. Works same way for IE and FF. I initiate long running process and try to navigate away with commandLink and golink. goLink works always, while commandLink get queued and triggers when long running process is finished.

Comment: @Nagh Strange.. I also decided to try on a test application using goLink and in my case i am not able to leave the page while child thread is waiting for termination in FF but works in IE and chrome. Here is a twist also if i use navigationContext.processAction and action="pprnav" with commandLink then it works in FF as well but i want full page redirection instead of PPR.

Comment: @JitenderKaswan Can you tell me your webcenter version?

Comment: @JitenderKaswan thats pretty outdated version. Consider upgrading to at least 11.1.1.5 and current 11.1.1.7 is much better with lots of new features ported from adf12. So your case could be a bug in this old version.

Comment: @Nagh Well !!! Thanks for your suggestion but i need to think about this because its not easy to upgrade as its an existing big project.

Comment: @JitenderKaswan You can make quick test in jdeveloper. Just get new and try it out. If this is a bug, then you can look for workarounds.

Comment: @Nagh May i know on which version you've tried(both Jdev & webcenter) ?

Comment: @JitenderKaswan 11.1.1.7 (current release).